# Permanent data that the user can not delete

Tags: android, database, file, sharedpreferences

Hi all:  I need to know if there is any way to make Android persistent data that the user can not delete, because if I use SharedPreferences or databases, it is possible that the user can delete all data from the Android menu, Settings - > applications -> Manage Applications -> "application name" -> Clear Data.

If I keep in the external memory also exist the possibility that the user delete or change memory device.
As always, thank you very much and sorry for my English.

Comment: There can not be anything like Permanent, user can delete your Application using same path you said.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way is to use a remote server to store data on...

Comment: If android gives you permission to write file in system file then you can do it. But i am not sure about it also not sure that user cant see this. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [Swarm's Cloud Data](http://swarmconnect.com/cloud_data) system.  It provides a system extremely simple API (very similar to SharedPreferences) for set/get operations.  Everything is saved to the cloud, and persists per user account.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, your application does not have access to such kind of functionality. The only option you have... is storing data into a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Store it on your cloud app server.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers, I ask whether to save data to a remote server is accepted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, If you do not want your users to be able to erase your data, you need to store it outside of the device, and access it via the internet.

You can use your own server for this, alternatively, I have used the Skiller SDK for my multiplayer game and noticed that they provide a simple data storage functionality (which frankly, i didn't use) but it seems like it would answers your needs.

Good luck.